# Firebase callable functions fail CORS redirect

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I am following the "Call Functions from Your App" documenation for Firebase and am running into the following error:

> Failed to load
>   https://us-central1-(redacted).cloudfunctions.net/secondAddMessage:
>   Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

This is a react app hosted with Firebase Hosting using `httpsCallable` to call a Firebase Cloud Function. It's my understanding that CORS is configured automatically and that I don't need to do anything with it. However, this is failing on a redirect. Can't seem to find any documentation out there to explain this.

Anyone know why this is happening? Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The firebase config on the react app had the wrong authDomain value. The web app was migrated from a different Firebase account, and the config info wasn't completely updated. Now that it has the correct authDomain, the CORS functionality is working.

Comment: Showing the config here would be helpful.

Comment: I don't have access to the config anymore or I would. It followed the sample config in the Firebase sample iOS project. I had to update the authDomain variable for the correct Firebase account.